# The Java type `javax.inject.Inject` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx

Migrated Xamarin.Android project to AndroidX and had to update some packages. Now I am unable to build my project and getting following error messages:

```
`javax.inject.Named` generated by: JavaX.Inject.INamed, Xamarin.JavaX.Inject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
`javax.inject.Scope` generated by: Javax.Inject.IScope, Scanbot.Xamarin.SDK.Dependencies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
`javax.inject.Qualifier` generated by: JavaX.Inject.IQualifier, Xamarin.JavaX.Inject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
The Java type `javax.inject.Inject` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.               
`javax.inject.Provider` generated by: JavaX.Inject.IProvider, Xamarin.JavaX.Inject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null               
`javax.inject.Inject` generated by: JavaX.Inject.IInject, Xamarin.JavaX.Inject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null               
`javax.inject.Qualifier` generated by: Javax.Inject.IQualifier, Scanbot.Xamarin.SDK.Dependencies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
The Java type `javax.inject.Provider` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.             
`javax.inject.Scope` generated by: JavaX.Inject.IScope, Xamarin.JavaX.Inject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
`javax.inject.Named` generated by: Javax.Inject.INamed, Scanbot.Xamarin.SDK.Dependencies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
The Java type `javax.inject.Scope` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.                
`javax.inject.Provider` generated by: Javax.Inject.IProvider, Scanbot.Xamarin.SDK.Dependencies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null               
`javax.inject.Singleton` generated by: JavaX.Inject.ISingleton, Xamarin.JavaX.Inject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
`javax.inject.Inject` generated by: Javax.Inject.IInject, Scanbot.Xamarin.SDK.Dependencies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null               
The Java type `javax.inject.Named` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.                
The Java type `javax.inject.Qualifier` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.                
`javax.inject.Singleton` generated by: Javax.Inject.ISingleton, Scanbot.Xamarin.SDK.Dependencies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null             
The Java type `javax.inject.Singleton` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.
```

Please advice how it can be fixed or how can I change the [Register] attribute and where it needs to be done. I cannot remove those packages, other packages depend on them.

Comment: Might not help, but after a major change such as that, quit VS, delete all bin and obj folders in the solution.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve tried that, did not help.

Comment: There is some conflict between the nuget packages in the project. See the pairs of package names after “generated by”, on each error line. Maybe some package(s) have to be deleted, need a different one to work with AndroidX. Unfortunately, the exact fix requires knowing what packages conflict. Make a new empty project in a new folder. Start adding the nugets you need. One at a time. Build after adding each one. Until you get errors again. Then add to question the packages you added, and the new list of errors.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you, deleted all packages from project and re-added them. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx#migration-tooling) , we'll need to make some manual namespace changes for scenarios the tool doesn't cover.

AndroidX replaces the `Android support libraries` ,  and so any references to Android support library types must be replaced with references to AndroidX types.

The following table shows the namespace changes

| Android support library namespace | AndroidX namespace |
| --- | --- |
| Android.Support.V4.App | AndroidX.Core.App |
| Android.Support.V4.Content | AndroidX.Core.Content |
| Android.Support.V4.App | AndroidX.Fragment.App |
| Android.Support.V7.App | AndroidX.AppCompat.App |
| Android.Support.V7.Widget | AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget |

More : https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/blob/main/mappings/androidx-class-mapping.csv.

Refer to the links for more details :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms5-migration#use-androidx-types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration

#### Update

Delete all the packages and re-add them in projects.

Comment: Thank you, I already changed namespace names. To solve the issue I had to remove all packages from project and re-add them.